# App crashes on using findViewWithTag and getTag

Tags: java, android, tags, android-view, android-xml

I am a novice android developer.
I have declared a 3x3 gridLayout in my activity layout, in which I have put 9 imageViews with tags from 0 to 8.
A snippet of the layout code is posted below:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/counter_topLeft"
            android:onClick="drop_in"
            android:tag="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />
```

In my main method, in the method `drop_in()`, I'm trying to check if user has called it or not, and if the system has called it, I'm trying to retrieve the ImageView by tags, by using a random number as tag.
Here is the `drop_in()` method:

```
public void drop_in(View view) // method invoked on tapping any grid cell
    {
        int i;
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
        i = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString()); // getting the associated tags or basically cell number
        if(isHuman)
        { // do some stuff and then 
            isHuman=false;
        }
        //  now app will perform actions and wait for user input to do stuff again
        if(!isHuman)
        {
            Random random=new Random();
            i=random.nextInt(9);

            Object o=i;
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout)
            myview=(View) group.findViewWithTag(o);
            Log.i("Info","View tag is "+myview.getTag().toString());
            isHuman=true;
         }
    }
```

In the logcat, it shows the following error:

```
2020-05-15 12:26:40.605 10000-10000/com.s090.tttsingleplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.s090.tttsingleplayer, PID: 10000
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.view.View.getTag()' on a null object reference
        at com.s090.tttsingleplayer.MainActivity.drop_in(MainActivity.java:133)
```

How can I retrieve the views using tags?

Comment: try this myview=(View) group.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(i));

Comment: why are you using `Object o=i`?

Comment: @CôngHải thanks, this worked!

Comment: @Omid.N used this because I was trying to use Object as tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line alse

ImageView counter = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter_topLeft);

myview=(View) group.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(i));

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote I have copied from [Official Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#tags) :

> ***Tags***
>
> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially
>   an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They
>   are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in
>   the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate
>   structure.

So you must not use tags to find them in runtime. My suggestion is to use an `int` array to store your `ImageView`s' IDs and use `Random` class to generate random indexes with that :

```
int[] imageviewIds={R.id.image1,R.id.image2 \* .etc*\};
Random random=new Random();
i=random.nextInt(9);
myview=(View) group.findViewById(imageIds[i]);
```

Comment: I could use that as well TBH and that's the right method as well. However to implement this I'll need to change the whole method. But I'll remember this for sure!

Comment: @Sanskar you won't need to change to the whole method. You just have to create the array in your activity class and use it wherever it is needed. As it is mentioned in the documentation it is preferable to use Id to make the reference to your views in the xml.